# Best way to load a custom error html file in a webview

Tags: java, android, webview

1. A custom html page is loaded in webview when some error has occurred(internet is disconnected, timeout...) and the failingUrl is saved in viewModel.
2. When reload button is pressed, it tries to reload the failingUrl.

The problem is every time I load the custom html file, it is called again in onPageStarted and failingUrl is cleared. So failingUrl is going to be null. How can I know if it is the error page or not when onPageStarted is being called?

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            //clear failingUrl
            viewModel.setFailingUrl(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            String htmlData ="<html><body>" + "ErrorNo: " + errorCode + "</body></html>";
            view.loadDataWithBaseURL(failingUrl, htmlData, "text/html", "UTF-8", failingUrl);
            //save failingUrl
            viewModel.setFailingUrl(failingUrl);
        }
    });
```

reloadButton:

```
reloadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           if (!viewModel.getFailingUrl()) {
              webView.loadUrl(viewModel.getFailingUrl());
              return;
           }
           webView.reload();
        }
});
```

I could clear the failingUrl when reloadButton is clicked, but it not a good idea. Because if I change the url when webView is back to normal, and press the reloadButton, it will reload the failingUrl.

Comment: Check the `url` in the `onPageStarted` method and see if it is your falling url ??

Comment: Should i post it as answer?

Comment: Please. And more detailed if you can.

Comment: Ok. I added one

Answer (score 0):

As Rahul Khurana said, check if it is the failingUrl in onPageStarted.
I did this way:

```
@Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
   super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
   if (viewModel.getFailingUrl != null) {
      if (!viewModel.getFailingUrl().equals(url)) {
         viewModel.setFailingUrl(null);
      }
   }
}
```

then in onClickListener:

```
reloadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           if (!viewModel.getFailingUrl()) {
              webView.loadUrl(viewModel.getFailingUrl());
              //added
              viewModel.setFailingUrl(null);
              return;
           }
           webView.reload();
        }
});
```

It seems to work! If the user loads a new url, that is different from failingUrl, the failingUrl wont be loaded when reload button is pressed.
And if the user tries to reload the failingUrl when theres no error in webView, the user will get the failingUrl reloaded and the failingUrl will be cleared.

I wish there was a better way to do this...

Answer (score 0):

In the `onPageStarted` method check if it is failing URL. You may need to hold the failing URL from `onReceivedError` method, somewhere so that when the network connection is back or the conditions are satisfied then you can load it.

```
@Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
   super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
   if (viewModel.getFailingUrl != null) {
      if (!viewModel.getFailingUrl().equals(url)) {
         viewModel.setFailingUrl(null);
      }
   }
}
```

At `reload` button clickListener event set the failing URL to null

```
reloadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           if (!viewModel.getFailingUrl()) {
              webView.loadUrl(viewModel.getFailingUrl());
              viewModel.setFailingUrl(null); // set the failing url to null
              return;
           }
           webView.reload();
        }
});
```